# Why can't I tighten my olive oil bottle?

Tags: storage-method, oil

It seems every olive oil bottle I buy lately is not made to be tightened all the way.  Why?

Comment: Sorry, if you want a real answer to this, you're going to need to ask about specific brands and describe your experiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oil bottles tend to be opened and closed many times, and the caps deform. They're often made of very thin metal and every time you do them up the metal spreads a little until the screw threads don't engage properly. The oil itself doesn't help as it lubricates the thread so the normal cue that the cap is tight enough -- at least partly due to increased friction -- isn't as noticeable as on other bottles

Plastic caps seem better than metal but it's still easy to over tighten them.

You need to be more gentle, especially when they're new. The better oils I buy have a plastic stopper inside the metal cap that seals without much force. The cheaper ones have the same structure moulded into the plastic cap, so the seal isn't on the thread.

Comment: Thanks, I had mistakenly suspected that the maker wanted some air exchange, but now I'll simply say that a glass bottle makes a tight fit more difficult.  Anyway, this might all change in 20 years since there is research showing cheaper PET plastics can replace glass for oil bottling (just like they already do for water bottling).